# JSON decode Array and insert in DB

Tags: php, json

I have some issue with a decoded Json object sended to a php file. I have tried some different format like this

```
{"2":"{Costo=13, ID=9, Durata_m=25, Descrizione=Servizio 9}","1":"{Costo=7, ID=8, Durata_m=20, Descrizione=Servizio 8}"}
```

or this.

```
[{"Costo":"7.5","ID":"3","Durata_m":"30","Descrizione":"Barba Rasoio"},{"Costo":"4.5","ID":"4","Durata_m":"20","Descrizione":"Barba Macchinetta"}]
```

In order the first, any suggestions helps me, then i have converted previous string using GSON, however php doesn't decode.

This is my php:

```
//Receive JSON
 $JSON_Android = $_POST["JSON"];
//Decode Json
$data = json_decode($JSON_Android, true);
foreach ($data['servizi'] as $key => $value) 
    { echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
 }
```

How can I access single elements of array? What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is show in `echo "FROM PHP:  " . $value;` ?

Comment: I haven't code here, but if I remember correctly, it's the string above without initial number {"1":

Comment: Well then check the answer..

Comment: For sure! I will test it tomorrow.

Comment: comment for result please..

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks @scaisEdge

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check the content in this way

```
//Receive JSON
$JSON_Android = $_POST["JSON"];
//Decode Json
$data = json_decode($JSON_Android, true);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) { 
    echo "FROM PHP:  " . $value;

    echo "Test : " .$value['ID'];

}
```

Comment: Here I am. This is the output of echo test: <b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'ID' in <b>D:\...etc

Comment: **bold** 'It Works!' Using string converted by GSON in this format [{"Costo":"7.5","ID":"3","Durata_m":"30","Descrizione":"Barba Rasoio"}] I'm able to access to elements of array. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your elements of {Costo=7, ID=8, Durata_m=20, Descrizione=Servizio 8}

are not properly formated as an array element. That is a pure string and not an array value.

This is a json object with 1 element of array:

```
{
  "1": {
    "Costo": 7,
    "ID": 8,
    "Durata_m": 20
  }
}
```

The Inside are json objects. Therefore your json string was not properly formated to operate with that logic. What you had was an element of a string. That is the reason why it was a valid json (passing jsonlint) but was not the correct one that you wanted to use.

**UPDATE**
Because this format is fix, I have a non-elegant way:

```
//Receive JSON
$JSON_Android = $_POST["JSON"];
//Decode Json
$data = json_decode($JSON_Android, true);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) { 
    //to separate each element
    $newArray = explode(',',$value);
    $newItem = explode('=', $newArray[1]);
    echo "ID". $newItem[1];
}
```

That would be the dirty way to do it ONLY IF THE PLACEMENT OF DATA IS FIX. (ie the second element of the first explode is always ID.

I will leave it to someone else to make the suggested code better. I would recommend more to ensure that the json you are receive is proper because as I explained, it is incorrectly formated and as an api developer, you want an adaptive way for any given client to use the data efficiently.

Comment: Thank you for response. I had imagined that problem was just this string, but i don't know how to change or reformat it. It cames from a listview selection on android listview, and i have followed some tutorial to convert to json object. Have you any suggest or solution?

Comment: @Jayelef I added more detail and suggested code with explanation, but it is not the 100% solution, you will need to take it and work with it.

Comment: Well, while you had suggested your code, i'm trying to change method to create the array. I'm just working yet, however i have copied your snippet and i have tested it. This is the output: <b>Warning</b>:  explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in <b>D:\inetpub...etc

Comment: Using GSON library, i have converted the string to send in this format [{"Costo":"4.5","ID":"4","Durata_m":"20","Descrizione":"Barba Macchinetta"},{"Costo":"7.5","ID":"3","Durata_m":"30","Descrizione":"Barba Rasoio"}], but now i'm not able to decode it in php file. Always error. Blob...(